# presence on multiple resources smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am trying to update the presence on three clients two of them are Adium & Pidgin and one my custom build app. when I send presence from my App it works sets available and status to "In Room":

```
 ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
   connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
   presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available,"In Room",1,Presence.Mode.available);

        connection.sendPacket(presence);
```

But when I update presence from other IM lets say Adium, it fails to update presence and status in situation when I have updated presence from my APP, other wise Adium and Pidgin works with each other. I realized that some thing is going wrong due to my APP. I implemented presence packet listener: if I change presence from Pidgin or Adium  this listener is listening it should listen

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener(){

        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet presencePkt) {

            Presence pres= ((Presence) presencePkt);
            presence.setPriority(1);// presence is global variable 

        switch(pres.getMode()){
            case available: presence.setMode(pres.getMode());
                            //connection.sendPacket(pres);
            break;
            case dnd: presence.setMode(pres.getMode());
                     //connection.sendPacket(pres);
            break;

            default :
                break;

        }


    }

}, new PacketTypeFilter(Presence.class));
```

Comment: I think you wanted to write that the Listener is never fired, right?

Comment: it fires certainly and I am getting my own presence, but when after getting my presence if I try to send new presence vis connection.sendPacket(pres). It continuously starts to send presence.

Answer (score 0):

Going with a custom `PresencePacketListener` is in 98% the wrong approach. Instead you want to add your own [`RosterListener`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/RosterListener.html) with [`Roster.addRosterListener()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html#addRosterListener%28org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterListener%29) to react on presence changes of entities in your Roster.

Make sure that both jabber entities have at least subscription mode *from* or *both*, so that the server will forward the presence stanzas to your client.

If you want to get the presences for the other resources/full JIDs of your account. Try [`Roster.getPresences(StringUtils.parseBareAddress(connection.getUser()))`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html#getPresences%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: but I don't want the presence of  other subscribers but presence of same account if it is loggin from different IM client. Roster.addlistener() can only get roster list/ buddy list. I am getting my own presence from other resources with custom listener. My question is that how can I update my presence on multiple clients if    I change presence from one client.... Hope you understood

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question then and try to find a good title. The other client decides how a bare JID is shown if multiple resources with different presence information is involved.

Answer (score 0):

I've just read your comments to Flow, this answer is late but others may need the same;

The answer is still to use a `RosterListener` as Flow suggested (based on my experiences using Smack).

With a RosterListener you will receive presence changes for your own user as well as other users (to and from will both be your own username). This means the roster is keeping track for you so you can use the `Roster#getPresences(username)` method to get an ordered list of your presence from different sources, you can get the username to supply dynamically by using `Roster#getUser()`

The doc [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html) covers the topic and basically explains that different modes have different priorities, so (for instance) if *any* client has you 'available' then using `Roster#getPresence(username)` (singular) will return available.

The Roster also allows you to set/change these priorities/ordering if you wish to. Hope this helps somebody!